# How do I retrieve an image's width and height using Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: images, advanced-custom-fields

Using a get_field('sampleImage'), how would I go about in order to get the image's width and height using the ACF plug-in? I need to be able to print out the img tag with width and height attributes because of a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ID for the attachment with `$attachment_id = get_field('field_name');`. When you have the ID you can use [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) to get the info associated with the image in an array. The images width and height are stored in cells named `width` and `height`.

```php
$attachment_id = get_field('field_name');
$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id);

$width = $metadata['width'];
$height = $metadata['height'];
```

Comment: Thank you! 
If you're reading this and looking for a solution - be sure to set the return value of these fields to Attachment ID in the ACF panel.